# How to import oracle dump from ec2 instance to RDS in AWS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am new to RDS in AWS.I have a database dump file that is residing on an `ec2 instance`. I have few questions :

1. How can I move the dump file to `RDS Instance`.
2. What will be the pre requisites to do this. I mean what client do I  need to install to do this.

Any help or lead is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: yeah but I didn't get anything

Comment: I have configured the ec2 instance which has the dump file. also I have configured oracle RDS instance. I have installed the oracle client on the ec2 instance. Now how to import the dump. that is q question. kindly help me out.

Comment: If you didn't understand anything in that document, I think you need to engage someone to do it for you.

Comment: can u help me out. now when I have set up the environment now the we can import the dump to rds using the standard procedure. what will be the utility ?

Comment: I think you would start with step 3 in the instructions I linked to.

Comment: can u tell me the normal steps to migrate the data to oracle server.

Comment: You haven't said what's confusing you about the instructions I've already linked to.

Comment: entire article is confusing :(

Comment: In that case I'm not sure you're going to be able to be helped in a forum like this.

Comment: the `admin/network` directory is also not there. Also the bin dir contains only `adrci  genezi  sqlplus`. I am not able to import the dump

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the official document is quite confusing and not clear when it comes to Oracle import of dump file.

There is another document step by step instructions from amazon at http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/strategies-for-migrating-oracle-database-to-aws.pdf and also a presentation at http://fr.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/dat308-28616289

Basically the process is :

1. you need to transfer files to Amazon RDS DB instance - Amazon offers an already defined `DATA_PUMP_DIR` so you would need to have a script to move your dump files from your EC2 instance to the Amazon RDS `DATA_PUMP_DIR`

The following script would do the job for you

```
use DBI;
use warnings;
use strict;

# RDS instance info
my $RDS_PORT=1521;
my $RDS_HOST="<my rds instance>";
my $RDS_LOGIN="<myuser>/*******";
my $RDS_SID="<ORCL_LIKE>"; 

#The $ARGV[0] is a parameter you pass into the script
my $dirname = "DATA_PUMP_DIR";
my $fname = $ARGV[0];

my $data = "dummy";
my $chunk = 8192;

my $sql_open = "BEGIN perl_global.fh := utl_file.fopen(:dirname, :fname, 'wb', :chunk); END;";
my $sql_write = "BEGIN utl_file.put_raw(perl_global.fh, :data, true); END;";
my $sql_close = "BEGIN utl_file.fclose(perl_global.fh); END;";
my $sql_global = "create or replace package perl_global as fh utl_file.file_type; end;";

my $conn = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host='.$RDS_HOST.';sid='.$RDS_SID.';port='.$RDS_PORT,$RDS_LOGIN, '') || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n");

my $updated=$conn->do($sql_global);
my $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_open);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":dirname", \$dirname, 12);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":fname", \$fname, 12);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":chunk", \$chunk, 4);
$stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n");

open (INF, $fname) || die "\nCan't open $fname for reading: $!\n";
binmode(INF);
$stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_write);
my %attrib = ('ora_type','24');
my $val=1;
while ($val> 0) {
  $val = read (INF, $data, $chunk);
  $stmt->bind_param(":data", $data , \%attrib);
  $stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n") ; };
die "Problem copying: $!\n" if $!;
close INF || die "Can't close $fname: $!\n";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_close);
$stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n") ;
```

make sure all your files are imported

```
select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) order by FILENAME;
```

2. Import your data from dump files to your RDS instance

you can run `impdp` or you can submit a job using PL/SQL script

```
declare
  h1    NUMBER;
begin

  h1 := dbms_datapump.open (operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'FULL', job_name => 'IMPORT_DUMP', version => 'COMPATIBLE');
  dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'IMPORT.LOG', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE);

  -- optional 
  dbms_datapump.set_parallel(handle => h1, degree => 8);

  dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'IMPORT.LOG', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => 3);
  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'KEEP_MASTER', value => 0);

  dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'HOST_01.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_DUMP_FILE);
  <repeat the add_file for all your files>

  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'INCLUDE_METADATA', value => 1);
  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD', value => 'AUTOMATIC');
  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'REUSE_DATAFILES', value => 0);
  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'SKIP_UNSUSABLE_INDEXES', value => 0);

  dbms_datapump.start_job(handle => h1, skip_current => 0, abort_step => 0);
  dbms_datapump.detach(handle => h1);
end;
/
```

The import is done and data available into your RDS db. you can clean your files from the `DATA_PUMP_DIR`, the following script would do the job

```
-- remove file from data pump dir
begin
utl_file.fremove ('DATA_PUMP_DIR','import.log');
utl_file.fremove ('DATA_PUMP_DIR','<name of file>.dmp');
end fremove;
/
```

Comment: HAve you got:  The current API cannot be executed because of inconsistencies between the API and the current definition of the job.
 Subsequent messages supplied by DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_STATUS
will further describe the error.