# How to upload oracle dump file to oracle database: AWS RDS

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-rds

I have oracle dump file in my AWS ec2 instance, I want to import this dump file to Oracle database in AWS RDS.

I tried using with Oracle SQL developer and also using Perl script.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

[How to import oracle dump from ec2 instance to RDS in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486198/how-to-import-oracle-dump-from-ec2-instance-to-rds-in-aws)

Using Oracle SQL Developer method, the 'Database Copy' option is not enabled.
Using Perl, getting a lot of error while running the script.

```
[root@ip-172-28-1-70 oracle]# perl dump_exp.pl     
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't locate DBD/Oracle.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 4) line 3.
    Perhaps the DBD::Oracle perl module hasn't been fully installed,
    or perhaps the capitalisation of 'Oracle' isn't right.
    Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Mem, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge.
     at dump_exp.pl line 23.
```

this both methods are not working for me, and am not aware of Perl.

Please suggest me if have any better method.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the "lots of errors". Without seeing these, it's hard to suggest you a good way on how to approach the situation.

Comment: please go through the error @Corion

Comment: The error is quite descriptive: `Perhaps the DBD::Oracle perl module hasn't been fully installed`. Most likely, this is the case.

Comment: Tried using cpan DBD::Oracle command & cpan> install DBD::Oracle, getting this at the end. YAML is also installed
'Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  ZARQUON/DBD-Oracle-1.76.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Failed during this command:
 ZARQUON/DBD-Oracle-1.76.tar.gz               : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 512'
@Corion

Comment: Yes, but that is a different problem. Most likely, the Oracle client libraries are not installed. You don't show the output of ` /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL` but most likely it tells you that. See also `https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-Oracle/` and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407513/perl-dbdoracle-module-installation

Comment: Thanks@Corion, Error is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS RDS does not allow directory access.

1. You need install Oracle XE on Amazon EC2.
2. Create db_link on Oracle XE EC2 between Oracle XE and Oracle RDS.
3. Use a db_link between Oracle XE and Oracle RDS to transfer files
       using the procedure DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.

If you can export using the original export `exp`, 
you can import from any workstation with oracle client and the original import utility `imp`.

Comment: I followed Oracle Data pump method by installing Oracle XE in EC2 instance, created db_link with RDS. Thanks @Dmitry